# Release a file lock on a COM DLL that has been instantiated via `CreateObject`

Tags: .net, vb.net, com

I have a .Net 4 WinForms app that generates a DLL, calls `CreateObject` on the generated DLL then calls one of several methods that the DLL contains. The DLL is eventually used by a separate app. This WinForms app is just to generate and test the DLL hence why it can generate the DLL multiple times.

The problem lies in the fact that calling `CreateObject` on the DLL locks the file to the process. The next time the DLL is generated it can't overwrite the previous DLL file on disk without closing the app completely and starting it again.

I've tried `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`, executing the `CreateObject` in a separate AppDomain, even setting the variable holding the COM object to a different COM object via `CreateObject`, manually calling `GC.Collect()` and a whole host of other things but none result in unlocking the file.

The code flow is basically (simplified and generic names, etc.):

```
...
' Compile and generate DLL that is COM enabled and works fine
...

Dim foo As Object = CreateObject("Bar.Foo")
foo.callMethod()

...
' Succeeds or fails then continues
...

...
' Clean up and remove the generated DLL     
foo = Nothing
File.Delete("C:\myassembly.dll")
...
```

Pretty standard usage. So my question is: is there a way to release a file lock on a COM DLL that has been instantiated via `CreateObject` without killing the process?

Note: this is a continuation of [this original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044452/registering-a-generated-vb-net-dll-assembly-programmatically-without-locking-the). I now have the DLL registering without locking the file but now the issue is with the CreateObject call not the DLL registration.

Comment: Is it possible that this is a timing issue? Can you wait for a while after setting `foo = Nothing` then try and delete the file. It may take a few instructions to actually remove the lock. You may need to Try your `GC.Collect` and `ReleaseComObject` again as well

Comment: I don't _think_ it is due to timing. I've had several additional instructions in between the `foo = Nothing` and the `File.Delete` at various points in troubleshooting this and it didn't help. I thought this at first too, that the processing was just going too quick for the file to unlock properly, but it doesn't appear to be the issue in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing [`Marshal.ReleaseComObject(foo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) in order to release the COM object, followed by P/Invoke [`CoFreeUnusedLibraries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to unload those DLL loaded through COM and unused any longer.

Comment: Whenever I call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(foo)` I get an exception `The object's type must be __ComObject or derived from __ComObject.`. It seems to think this isn't a true COM class despite having all of the `ComClass` and `ComVisible` decorators. Looking at it in the watch window, it is indeed giving a type of "Bar.Foo" instead of "__ComObject". Did I screw something up?